# SSRS Configuration option to turn off SQL.LOG file?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, db2, odbc

Recently we noticed that all reports in SSRS native platform have slowed down significantly and the disk was getting chewed up at a rather brisk pace. Upon some investigation, it was found that there is a new SQL.Log file that has come up in this folder:

C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp

All the data coming from database is first being written to this file. It is taking a long time to write this file before the report can be rendered thus slowing down everything. As useful as this trace/log maybe, we want to find out how to turn it off and cannot seem to find it anywhere in the documentation or help forums.

Any information on what it is and how it can be turned off would be helpful.

Some more information on stack:
- Reportserver: MSSQLSERVER version 10.50.4000.0
- Data is coming from IBM DB2
- Connection is being made using ODBC dsn
- Reports are published on native Reports platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL.LOG file is an ODBC tracing feature set in the ODBC admin tool, it's not specific to SSRS. See [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268591) and [this MSDN one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711020%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's likely that someone enabled tracing [for troubleshooting purposes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2007/11/10/odbc-tracing.aspx) and then either forgot to disable it, or didn't realize how large the file can become. You should be able to simply disable it in the ODBC admin tool.

Comment: Thanks Pondlife, sorry about the delayed "acceptance".... better late than never.

Comment: @AshArora No problem :-)